# click specific area inside pixelsearch?

Tags: autohotkey

my script is working fine. but mostly it is having a hard time to click the targeted pixel. because it mostly clicks only in side.(i guess it only click the first pixel it sees. which is the sides pixels of a square) any idea how can click the middle area inside of pixelsearch?

[image: http://i60.tinypic.com/eg7fb6.jpg]

```
Loop {
;<<-- this is the color of green boxed pixel
PixelSearch, X, Y, 0, 0, %A_ScreenWidth%, %A_ScreenHeight%, 0x00FF00, 0, fast
        if(ErrorLevel=0) {
        MouseClick, left, %X%, %Y%
        sleep, 500


        }
        else {

            send {f9}

        }
    }
return
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply alter the click coordinates, couldn't you?

```
PixelSearch, X, Y, 0, 0, %A_ScreenWidth%, %A_ScreenHeight%, 0x00FF00, 0, fast
if(ErrorLevel=0) {
    newX := X + 50
    newY := Y + 50
    MouseClick, left, %newX%, %newY%
}
```

Another suggestion: use ImageSearch instead of PixelSearch

Comment: Yup, or maybe a double search?